# Where does htaccess cut query string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is my htaccess

```
php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
php_flag session.use_only_cookies on
Options +FollowSymLinks

            RewriteEngine On


            RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://automaticheskie-vorota.ru/? [R=301,L]


            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]

            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]

            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
            RewriteRule .* index.php [F]



            RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

If I go to http://site.ru/?utm_source=123 site does 301 redirect to http://site.ru I don't want it to do so.
Can't understand where does it cut query strings in htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `?` from your first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://automaticheskie-vorota.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And make sure to test in a new browser

Comment: yeah, that was first thing I tried and It didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you've confirmed that your modified .htaccess file was successfully uploaded or rewritten to the right place, and you didn't put the new copy in the wrong place, and the old copy wasn't read-only (file edits or uploads ignored).

You could start debugging it by commenting out (#) one of the three "blocks" of RewriteCond/Rules, and seeing which block is causing the unwanted behavior you describe. Then you can narrow it down to a specific RewriteCond or RewriteRule within that block. You should also add some comments about what each of the three blocks is supposed to be doing, to aid with future maintenance.

By the way, you should move the php_flag (as well as php_value) commands to a php.ini (or similar) file, if at all possible. Eventually your server will be upgraded and you will get Internal Server errors with those commands still in .htaccess.